# Mongodb - How to select only "n" columns

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with 15 columns and want to bring only 4, but if I use this it brings all columns

```
tb.find_one({'column1':'value'},{'_id':1, 'column1':1, 'column4':1, 'column2':1})
```

Do I have to specify all the columns that I don't want?

Comment: do you use pymongo ?

Comment: try using double quote instead of single quote when using pymongo

Comment: "try using double quote instead of single quote when using pymongo" - this will make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [aggregation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/aggregation.html) pipeline query. Using [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), and [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) can allow certain fields of a document matching specific criteria to be returned.

PyMongo example:

```
# matches all documents with "column1" value of "value"
stage_1 = {"$match": {"column1": "value"}}

# pulls the values "_id", "column1", "column4", and "column2" into the query response
stage_2 = {"$project": {"_id": 1, "column1": 1, "column4": 1, "column2": 1}}

# limits the number of responses to 1
stage_3 = {"$limit": 1}

pipeline = [stage_1, stage_2, stage_3]

results = list(tb.aggregate(pipeline))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the field(s) you want to exclude by setting them to 0 or false in the projection clause. All fields in the document except the ones you specified to exclude will be included in the query result.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "column1": 1
},
{
  "column10": 0,
  "column11": 0,
  "column12": 0,
  "column13": 0
})
```

Here is a [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bIJYB_4UtA-) for your reference.

Ref: [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection)

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is exactly correct. If you only want those columns, specify them with the `1` inclusion operator. I'd be curious to know what you see that suggests otherwise:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

tb = MongoClient()['mydatabase'].tb

tb.insert_one({f'column{x}': 'value' for x in range(15)})

print(tb.find_one({'column1': 'value'}, {'_id': 1, 'column1': 1, 'column4': 1, 'column2': 1}))
```

prints:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5fd35c58b9e268dbd76d5299'), 'column1': 'value', 'column2': 'value', 'column4': 'value'}
```